# Is it safe to give candies to my parrot?

Tags: diet, birds, parrots

Can I give candies to my gray parrot? He like candies and cookies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, many animals, including parrots, should not be given foods very high in sugar, fat, or sodium. It is not technically toxic, but too much of these things can cause various medical issues. There are also a variety of foods that are toxic or possibly toxic to parrots that can be found in sweets:

- chocolate
- licorice
- xylitol - a sugar substitute that can be found in sugar free candies
- peanuts
- dairy (not toxic, but parrots are definitely lactose intolerant)

There are also other foods that are toxic that are less likely to be found in sweets. The following is not necessarily a comprehensive list of all things that are poisonous to parrots.

- Avocado
- Mushrooms (generally of the varieties not safe for human consumption either)
- Fruit seeds and pits such as apple seeds
- Plants from the allium family (garlic, onions, and so forth)
- Plants from the nightshade family (not including the fruit, as in tomatoes are okay)
- Comfrey, the herb
- Leaves from the rhubarb plant

Answer (score 0):

"Safe" is an illusion. The "safest" thing to do is to not being born.

I know parrots who eat a little bit of chocolate now and then. They are still alive.

Xylitol is not "artificial", it is birch sugar. Some people seem to compare it to aspartame (which is complete and utter nonsense).

Some people also seem to think that the bacteria in our saliva are poisonous to parrots. My own experience proves that this is NOT the case.

Then there is this narrative about parrots being lactose intolerant. That too, according to my own experience, is nonsense. Our parrots eat yogurt every day and after many years, they still live happily without ever having diarrhea.

Comment: I always assume people calling xylitol "artificial" just use this word as a misnomer for "sugar substitute". And xylitol's natural origin doesn't deny the fact that it is actually toxic to dogs and cats - I'm not familiar with its effects on birds, though. Also, lactose is digested by bacteria during lactic fermentation in which yogurt is made, it gets converted to lactic acid; yogurt, like all fermented milk products, doesn't contain significant amounts of lactose.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! It is not common here to criticize another answer via a second answer. For helpful critics, like hints how to do better or questions for clarification, the comments are used (and firsthand the voting!). And yes, you could not use comments until now, because a basic amount of point is needed, which secures, that the user have some experience before the first comment. Your option to "critical doubt" the other answer is to write an own answer to the question, which directs the questioner. The question in this case is very short and do not includes "safe" or "lactose" in it ;)